# Unity Quaternion.LookRotation(x) and Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, x) give different values

Tags: unity-game-engine

As stated in question title. This upends my entire understanding of what these methods do.

```
Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(1, 1, 0), Vector3.up);
```

This gives axis angle of 98.42105 degrees around vector (-0.36, 0.86, 0.36), and I have no idea where these numbers come from.

```
Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
```

This gives axis angle of 89.99999 degrees around vector (-0.71, 0.71, 0.00), which is expected.

Can someone please explain the source of my misunderstanding? What is "LookRotation" doing if not using "forward" as a starting point and then turning your metaphorical head to look at the given vector direction?

Also, I thought FromToRotation always assumes an up vector of Vector3.up. Otherwise how does it know what direction is up?

Comment: Depends how exactly you use and apply those ... `LookRotation` would return the final world rotation, `FromToRotation` rather only a delta rotation you would have to **add** to your current one

Comment: How is LookRotation calculated if not assuming you started by looking forward? Shouldn't LookRotation(Vector3.forward) return an identity quaternion (no rotation)?

Answer (score 1):

Just make a quick test applying those rotations to objects and just observe their euler angles

| `LookRotation` | `FromToRotation` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

- `LookRotation` results in the object being rotated to euler `-45, 90, 0`

  [`LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) definitely uses the second `up` parameter and applies some "sanatizing" and goes

  > Z axis will be aligned with forward, **X axis aligned with cross product between forward and upwards**, and Y axis aligned with cross product between Z and X.

  this is done to avoid any `Z-axis` rotation which in the most game etc use cases would be undesired.
- `FomToRotation` results in euler `-45, 90, 45`

  The `FromToRotation` rather simply use the shortest axis rotation it can find (like e.g. https://discussions.unity.com/t/whats-the-source-code-of-quaternion-fromtorotation/227717/2) to only align the `Z`-axis with the given direction without enforcing any specific up vector, in your case the `Cross(from, to)` is the axis your are rotating around (= your `(-0.71, 0.71, 0.00)`)

  Which would also answer

  > Also, I thought FromToRotation always assumes an up vector of Vector3.up. Otherwise how does it know what direction is up?

  => It doesn't.

So in short: `LookRotation` aligns two axes, `FromToRotation` only aligns a single axis.

Answer (score 1):

## Why do I get different values?

[`LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) and [`FromToRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) might look similar at first glance, but they do very different things and hence have very different results. The official documentation is rather sparse, so I'll try to explain in more words.

### LookRotation

this method specifies the direction the object is pointing (looking) in as well as its orientation. Think about yourself looking at a screen. You could be looking at it with your head upright or tilted to the side. The first argument specifies what direction you are looking in, while the second specifies what direction the top of your head is **trying** to point to as close as it can.

The Quaternion that this method returns describes a rotation from the unrotated state to the desired rotation.

### FromToRotation

this method only specifies the direction that the object is pointing. Think of it as being asked to point a laser in some direction. You will do so without really thinking about the way that your wrist is rotated. You will simply do as is most convenient.

The Quaternion that this method returns describes a rotation from the current rotation to the desired rotation.

## Where do these values come from?

The documentation is opaque on the implementation of the methods themselves, but the math is known. I will show you how the functions might look internally, so you (or your calculator) can follow them step by step and explain the different implementations. The following code can be run in the unity engine and simply proves the custom implementation correct.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var qOL = Quaternion.LookRotation(new Vector3(1, 1, 0), Vector3.up);
        var qCL = LookRotation(new Vector3(1, 1, 0), Vector3.up);
        var qOR = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
        var qCR = FromToRotation(Vector3.forward, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));

        Debug.Log("ORIGIN LookRotation: " + qOL);
        RotInfo(qOL);
        Debug.Log("CUSTOM LookRotation: " + qCL);
        RotInfo(qCL);

        Debug.Log("ORIGIN FromToRotation: " + qOR);
        RotInfo(qOR);
        Debug.Log("CUSTOM FromToRotation: " + qCR);
        RotInfo(qCR);
    }

    public static Quaternion LookRotation(Vector3 forward, Vector3 upwards)
    {
        //calc new ortagonal directions
        Vector3 newForward = forward.normalized;
        Vector3 newRight = Vector3.Cross(upwards, newForward).normalized;
        Vector3 newUp = Vector3.Cross(newForward, newRight).normalized;

        //fill matrix
        Matrix4x4 mat = Matrix4x4.identity;
        mat.SetColumn(0, newRight);
        mat.SetColumn(1, newUp);
        mat.SetColumn(2, newForward);

        //calc quaternion
        Quaternion quat = Quaternion.identity;
        quat.w = Mathf.Sqrt(1.0f + mat.m00 + mat.m11 + mat.m22) / 2.0f;
        float q4 = quat.w * 4;
        quat.x = (mat.m21 - mat.m12) / q4;
        quat.y = (mat.m02 - mat.m20) / q4;
        quat.z = (mat.m10 - mat.m01) / q4;

        return quat;
    }

    public static Quaternion FromToRotation(Vector3 fromDirection, Vector3 toDirection)
    {
        //calc rot angle
        float angleHalfRad = Vector3.Angle(fromDirection, toDirection) / 2 * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

        //calc rot axis
        Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(fromDirection, toDirection).normalized;
        axis *= Mathf.Sin(angleHalfRad);

        //calc quaternion
        Quaternion quat = new Quaternion(axis.x, axis.y, axis.z, Mathf.Cos(angleHalfRad));

        return quat;
    }

    public void RotInfo(Quaternion q)
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Acos(q.w);
        Vector3 vec = new Vector3(q.x, q.y, q.z);
        vec /= Mathf.Sin(angle);
        angle *= Mathf.Rad2Deg * 2;
        Debug.Log(angle + " " + vec);
    }
}
```

### LookRotation

As the documentation mentions the method calculates the cross product of forward and up to get the new X-axis (newRight) and the cross of the "newRight" with the "newForward" for the Y-axis. All these new Axis are normalized and passed into a transformation matrix. The Quaternion can then be calculated from this matrix. If you want to know more about the math you can read [here](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/index.htm)

### FromToRotation

Calculating the Quaternion when given a vector of rotation and an angle is straight forward. The angle of rotation is simply the angle between the two vectors. The axis of rotation can be obtained by cross product of the two vectors. The X, Y and Z component of the Quaternion are the rotation axis vector multiplied with the Sin of the half rotation angle. The W component is the Cos of the half rotation angle.